# Computing Document Similarity Matrices in Sphinx?

Tags: ruby, lucene, similarity, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

Does Sphinx provide a way to precompute document similarity matrices?  I have looked at Sphinx/Solr/Lucene; it seems Lucene is able to do this indirectly using Term Vectors [Computing Document Similarity with Term Vectors](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2011/10/computing-document-similarity-using.html).

Currently I am using the [tf-idf-similarity gem](https://github.com/opennorth/tf-idf-similarity) to do these calculations, but it is incredibly slow as the dataset grows; something like On^(n-1!).

Currently trying to find a faster alternative to this.  Lucene seems like a potential solution, but it doesn't have as much support within the Ruby community so if Sphinx has a good way of doing this that would be ideal.

Just to clarify; I am not trying to do live search similarity matching, which appears to be the most common use case for both Lucene and Sphinx, I am trying to precompute a similarity matrix that will create a similarity between all documents with the dataset.  This will subsequently be used in data visualizations for different types of user analysis.

Also anyone with prior experience doing this I'm curious about benchmarks. How it looks in terms of time to process and how much computing power and/or parallelization were you using with reference to number of documents and doc size average.

Currently it is taking about 40 minutes for me to process roughly 4000 documents and about 2 hours to process 6400 records.  Providing the 2 different sizes and times here to give an indication of the growth expansion so you can see how slow this would become with significantly large datasets.